# If I developed an iOS app, how can other people use it without publishing the app into app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

My friends are using iPhone. They want me to develop an iPhone app for them. Not commercial using, just for daily life. I do have an iOS developer account (which cost me $99 / year). I don't want to publish it into App Store. If I have developed this app, how can my friends use the app?

I remember a couple of years before(I didn't learn IT at that time), I am able to install an app without downloading them from app store. It seems include "open something in safari", "trust something", "agree something" etc.

Could someone give me more details please? Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/custom-apps/ or https://developer.apple.com/testflight/, most likely.

Comment: An unlisted app may also be appropriate

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to publish the application you can use Apple's Enterprise program.

See more here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/
But it has prerequisites *Eligibility section.

Another option is to use TestFlight to distribute as a beta tester.
https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: Enterprise is no longer an option. Apple closed the Enterprise development platform for small businesses of less than 100 employees.

Comment: "The Apple Developer Enterprise Program is only for the internal use and distribution of proprietary apps in specific use cases that are not adequately addressed with public apps on the App Store, custom apps through Apple Business Manager or Ad Hoc distribution, or beta testing through TestFlight. Your proprietary app must be developed by you for use on Apple platforms."